# i am trying to insert data in database using retrofit android

Tags: android, retrofit

when trying to insert database. null values are inserting not the actual data please help me out where went wrong.

//request
{
"name":"xxxx",
"email":"idfjd",
"password":"fb",
"gender":"male"}

//response
{
    "status": "Success",
    "msg": "Successfully inserted"
}

private void userSignUp() {

```
    //defining a progress dialog to show while signing up
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Signing Up...");
    progressDialog.show();

    //getting the user values
    final RadioButton radioSex = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    String gender = radioSex.getText().toString();


    //building retrofit object
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    //Defining retrofit api service
    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    //Defining the user object as we need to pass it with the call
    User user = new User("asd", "ig", "hdk", "kd");

    //defining the call
    Call<Result> call = service.createUser(
            user.getName(),
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(),
            user.getGender()
    );

    //calling the api
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            //hiding progress dialog
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            //displaying the message from the response as toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //if there is no error
            if (!response.body().getError()) {
                //starting profile activity
                finish();
                SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(response.body().getUser());
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

// User class
public class User {

```
private int id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String password;
private String gender;

public User(String name, String email, String password, String gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public User(int id, String name, String email, String gender){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public User(int id, String name, String email, String password, String gender) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKUjV.png)

please tell me whats the wrong with the code

//Apiservices class

public interface APIService {

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Owner/api.php?f=test_c")
Call<Result> createUser(
        @Field("name") String name,
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password,
        @Field("gender") String gender);
```

}

//Api Url

public class APIUrl {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://dev.anyemi.com/webservices/omrooms/";
}

Comment: Have you checked API ? Pls Post APIService and User classes also.

Comment: Hii pradeep ji, i posted user and result class and api classes also... please check and help me out

Comment: Have you tried the answer I posted? any updates?

Answer (score 0):

in user class you don't need id, that's autoincrement column,

Result class is for response so it has nothing with create user , check the createUser method in your api interface

first check your api with postman to make sure it's work

Comment: public interface APIService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Owner/api.php?f=test_c")
    Call<Result> createUser(
            @Field("name") String name,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("gender") String gender);
}

Comment: i never use url like that before and i don't know it work or not, you can handel url in server side code

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the hard coded parameter "?f=test_c", Retrofit automatically add "?" followed by parameters you are passing through @Field.
Try @POST("Owner/api.php") and passing parameters through @Field.